# RegExp replace (node.js) не работает корректно

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, json, node.js

Здравствуйте, функция в Javascript RegExp (node.js) не работает корректно, мне нужно получить число с запятой, вот данные:
299,00 р.
379,00 z
150,00 р.
Вместо считывания 299,00 с запятой, он записывает 299000 игнорируя запятую.
Код:

```
price = price_text.replace(/[^.\d]/g,"").replace( /^([^\.]*\.)|\./g, '$1' );
price = Math.floor(price);
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Так Вы же сами первым `replace`'ом убираете из строки всё, кроме цифр и точки. Запятая, естественно, тоже убирается.

Comment: Я думаю, RegExp работает таки корректно, просто выражение которое вы в него забили - даёт не тот результат, который вы ожидаете.

Comment: Перепробывал несколько вариантов с помощью reg101 для подбора, если я убираю 1-ый replace, получаю NULL. можете помочь оставить запятую?

Answer (score 0):

я думаю так проще и вместо replace использовать match с флагом g

```
\d+,?\d+(?=\s)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, не получилось( результат - NULL

Comment: if( (!price) && (_this.selectors[row.competitor_id]) ){
      _this.selectors[row.competitor_id].forEach(function(selector){
       price_text = $(selector.selector).text();
       if (price_text){
        price = price_text.replace(/[^.\d]/g, "").replace( /^([^\.]*\.)|\./g, '$1' );
           price = Math.floor(price);
           
        return;
       }
      });
     } //Весь код, отдает NULL если заменить на match вместо replace

Comment: @BloodKnight match возвращает массив из найденных совпадений.

Comment: а replace возвращает строку, верно? мне скорее строку надо, чем массив, может подскажете как переделать вот этот replace: price_text.replace(/[^.\d]/g, "") чтобы он читал и запятую?

Comment: @BloodKnight можете воспользоваться методом join https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: но ведь это не массив а строка... Я попробывал, получил все равно NULL((( Может с replace есть какие-то еще варианты?

Comment: @BloodKnight у вас match возвращает массив,вы хотели строку вот я Вам и предложил воспользоваться join

Comment: А все понял) Я еще новичек, и я плохо понимаю что здесь происходит) Может покажете пример как это сделать? Буду очень благодарен)